# How to compare two formatted string times (i.e. in HH:mm)

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I understand that NSDates could easily be compared using a function such as `if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending)`. However, I am interested in comparing two *times* only that were formatted with a `NSDateFormatter` and appears as `HH:mm`. For example, if I wanted to compare `07:20` with `08:10` and see which of the time is later, how would I be able to do this?

Edit: I understand a hacky way of doing it would be looking at each of the `HH:mm` digits and see which one is greater, but was wondering if there may be a time comparison function built into `NSDate`?

Thanks!

Comment: If I remember well `NSDate` holds a `timeSince1970`, that the value used to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two times using 24-hour format, then simply compare the two strings.

```
NSString *time1String = ... // some time in HH:mm
NSString *time2String = ... // some time in HH:mm

if ([time1String compare:time2String] == NSOrderedDescending) {
} else {
}
```

The string comparison will work as long as the hour and minutes are both two digits and the hour is in 24 hour format.

Comment: Great idea - this would be the best way to do it!

Comment: This is the best way only if you already have a need to format the `NSDate` into that specific format (which seems to be what you have). Otherwise this is not a good approach.